# Is it possible for sucrose to hydrolyse in water with a small amount of weak acid at room temperature?

Tags: hydrolysis

Sucrose hydrolysis in the industry is done using HCl and heat. On the other hand I know that bee keepers add some of acetic  or citric acid to wet sugar to prepare emergency food supply for bees, what is called Sugar Board. After preparation the Sugar Board is kept for a month to "cure".

I'm wondering if a period of one month and weak acid are enough conditions for sucrose to hydrolyse in room temperature.

Beekeepers are doing that to achieve some results:

1. the acidic environment of the sugar mixture is similar to the acidity of natural nectar and honey
2. the acidic environment blocks the development of molds and bacterias in the hive
3. It is easier to create a plastic mixture when acid is added
4. glucose and fructose are more natural energy sources for bees.

First two points are clear, the third one comes from practice, but real question is the last one. Is it possible that crystal sucrose (the one used to sweet a tea) with weak acid will hydrolyse into glucose and fructose without heating?

Comment: Your heating only makes such reaction faster, so if you don't mind waiting a month...

Comment: I am willing to wait for a month, but can I be assured that this process will not take a year? Will hydrolysis work for crystal sugar that is not dissolved in water?